# MySQL 5.6 - How to create a read-only table sorted by insertion order

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with MySQL 5.6. In all of my use-cases I build a read-only table to then query.

The common use-case of my customers is to sort results by insertion order. We even added a column with index that defines insertion order. The dilemma is if we should inject an "ORDER BY" to queries (unless another sort was requested by users).

One of the guys said it might hurt performance, which sounds reasonable. He also said that there is no configuration that ensures table's order since table might be updates - although in our case the table is always read-only.

Is there a way to define a read-only table that does ensure a specific order to avoid injecting "ORDER BY" in every query? Meaning it will somehow save the table in a defined order to avoid performance penalty?

Will be happy for any suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, the only way to ensure and order in SQL is using ORDER BY in your query. If you have appropiate indexes, it shouldn  be a performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

No.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering in the table unless you specify an `order by`.

What you can do is have an index on the column you want to order by.  Then, MySQL does not actually need to sort the data -- it just needs to read the index.  Or, if you can, you can make the column you want to order by a primary key.  This makes sense if your column is really an `auto_increment` column.

Comment: 'SQL tables represent unordered sets' -  I often see this statement on this site but have never been able to find a reference for it..

Comment: @P.Salmon "SQL-99 Complete, Really" p.653: "if you omit the [ORDER BY] clause, your DBMS will return the rows in some random order". Here's an online version: https://crate.io/docs/sql-99/en/latest/chapters/34.html#order-by-clause In practice, it's not _random_, because it's likely to return rows in the same order repeatedly. But it's _implementation-dependent_.

Comment: @bill karwin the reference is an assertion it doesn't explain the why (to my satisfaction) but this is not a the place for this discusssion - I will keep looking. thanks anyway.

Comment: It really goes back the definition in mathematics of a _set_. Sets are unordered collections. In Codd's vision of a relational database, a relation (aka table) is a _set of rows_ with a header to define its columns. By definition, this means the relation is unordered.

Comment: It seems weird because my use-case seems to be very common. I get that the order is implementation-specific and not guaranteed by SQL language itself but it's surprising that there's no implementation to support such a case. After all it makes no sense to re-order a table again and again by the same key if it's a read-only table and ALWAYS needs to be ordered by the same key..

After all any SQL implementation has to satisfy SQL languages guarantees but it might satisfy more guarantees...

Comment: @MaBekitsur . . . You are missing the point.  If you sort by the primary key, the database optimizer may not need to do a sort at all.  However, that is all "under the hood".  The optimizer chooses the best execution plan.